# When creating a plugin, how do I correctly submit data to my custom database?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I've been following the steps to create a plugin with a settings page and I have files for settings-callbacks.php and settings-register.php, but I'm not certain where to go from here. The button displays, but do I have query functions within the callback function? How would you do this?

```
//I've added a section for a button

add_settings_section(
    'new_listing_submit',
    'Add new listing',
    'new_listing_submit',
    'simpledir'
);


// I've created a callback function that displays the button.


function new_listing_submit(){

    echo "<form action=''>
      Add New: <input type='text' name='dir'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit-new-listing' class='button button-primary' value='Save Changes'>  
    </form>";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Use the **wp_nonce_field** field in your form. The nonce field is used to validate that the contents of the form came from the location on the current site and not somewhere else.

2-  Then in the page where it is being submitted to, you may verify it using the **wp_verify_nonce()** function.

For more details you can check below link.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nonce_field/

```
  <?php
    function new_listing_submit(){
            //Added wp_nonce_field filed in form
            echo "<form action=''  method='post'>".
              wp_nonce_field( '_wpsubmit-new-listing_action', '_wpsubmit-new-listing' )."
              Add New: <input type='text' name='dir'>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit-new-listing' class='button button-primary' value='Save Changes'>  
            </form>";

        }

        function submit_new_list() {
                if ( isset( $_POST['_wpsubmit-new-listing'] ) || wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpsubmit-new-listing'], '_wpsubmit-new-listing_action' ) ) {

                    //Process the form

                }
        }

        //Call submit_new_list functiuon with init hook
        add_action( 'init', 'submit_new_list');
```

Comment: Thats very useful, but I get Undefined index: _wpsubmit-new-listing. Any idea why?

Comment: I tried It's working for me. Are you using post method?

Comment: Add  wp_nonce_field( '_wpsubmit-new-listing_action', '_wpsubmit-new-listing' ) in your form. If did not add you will get Undefined index:_wpsubmit-new-listing

Comment: Yes I added the nonce field just like your example.

Comment: Now It should work. I tried the same It's working for me. If you update the latest code will see

Comment: Is it because I never checked if $_post['dir'] isset prior to checking the nonce? I did that and it removed the error.